# Tow types of user logged in the same login form - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, authentication

I'm working with asp.net web application and i have tow types of users in my website and each one has it's own table in the database : `Seller` and `DeliveryMan`. I have done them separately (in the DB)for some reason and i need to do it like that so please don't consider this as an answer ! i have created a login form that works with first user `Seller` but my problem how i can allow the `DeliveryMan` to login in the same form ? please any help ?

login form :

```
protected void ValidateUser(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
        {

            int userId = 0;
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Seller_Validate_User"))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Login1.UserName);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Login1.Password);
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    userId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                    con.Close();
                }
                switch (userId)
                {
                    case -1:
                        Login1.FailureText = "Username and/or password is incorrect.";
                        break;
                    case -2:
                        Login1.FailureText = "Account has not been activated.";
                        break;
                    default:
                        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Login1.UserName, Login1.RememberMeSet);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can search seller table if username and password matches set credentials to seller, if not search deliveryman table and if that matches set credentials to that, otherwise show error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a user can exist in seller & DeliveryMan tables then

- you should create a user role table
- you should query on seller & DeliveryManwith priority follow high permission

If a user only exists in seller or DeliveryMan table then

- You should check a user is exist in seller table
- If user isn't exist in seller table then you continue to check exist in DeliveryMan
- If user is exist in seller table then you return that user

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to have a common users table that has your login info a userType.  Once they've logged in, you can use the user type to pick which table to look for that person in.